# How do I add an onclick Handler in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

'm using the [ad-Gallery](http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/#ad-image-0) code in my asp.net application.
I've changed it a bit to be generic, because I wanted to download pictures from my database.
It means that all the implementation is in the code behind (here's a piece of my C# code):

```
ul.Attributes.Add("class", "ad-thumb-list");
            tabs.Controls.Add(ul);
            int i = 1;
                foreach (Products item in _PicturesPage)
                {
                    ul.Controls.Add(li);
                    anchor.Attributes.Add("href", item.ImagePath);
                    image.Attributes.Add("src", "../Images/pictures/thumbs/"+i+".jpg");
                    image.Attributes.Add("title","A title for 12.jpg");
                    image.Attributes.Add("alt", "This is a nice, and incredibly descriptive, description of the image");
                    image.Attributes.Add("class","image3");
                    li.Controls.Add(anchor);
                    anchor.Controls.Add(image);
                    i++;
                }
```

I want to know if it's possible to intercept a click in one of the hyperlink ()?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a JavaScript event handler:

```
anchor.Attributes.Add("onclick", "YourJavaScriptFunction();");
```

Be sure to return `false` from the handler, if you want to prevent navigation to the link's `href`.

If `anchor` is an instance of `HtmlAnchor` you can use:

```
anchor.ServerClick += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // do stuff
    };
```

Comment: it can't be a C# function in the code behind.
I don't realy understand javascript

Comment: If it is an `HtmlAnchor` it has the `ServerClick` Event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.serverclick.aspx

Comment: I wrote this: anchor = new HtmlAnchor();
            anchor.Attributes.Add("onserverclick", "HtmlAnchor_Click");
            anchor.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
And then this function:protected void HtmlAnchor_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            string ic = "fkjfkm";
        }
but it doesn't work. thank you anyway

Comment: Don't do this. Use `anchor.ServerClick += HtmlAnchor_Click;`
For more Information on events see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx

Comment: doesn't work.
well, I think i need to call a C# function from my javascript code.